# Can conditions crit?

Tags: guild-wars-2

Is it possible for a condition to crit?

I haven't seen any of the dot numbers with crit. So that could indicate that dots don't crit, but I could have missed it, the numbers are flying pretty fast when using conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, conditions cannot crit. This is by design.

If you want to increase the damage of conditions, you need to gear for... condition damage.